# Service Worker working on http

Tags: javascript, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, service-worker

So, I found a site where service worker allow block popup is coming on http. The site opens a https page of same domain though.

But as far as I have tried and researched, even that is not allowed. [Read here](https://github.com/slightlyoff/ServiceWorker/issues/700)

Here is the link to the website http://trak.in/

I am just curious how it's working.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The website is asking permission for showing notifications, which doesn't require HTTPS (you can show notifications without a service worker, you need the service worker only to receive push notifications).

Then, it's opening the HTTPS popup to register the user for push notifications using a service worker.

P.S.: The issue you're linking doesn't say anything about popups, it's about iframes.